# ItemsControl with 2 data templates (one for each object)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm working on a WPF application, using MVVM.
In my ViewModel I have 2 `ObservableCollection` objects, and I want to display each one differently.
The collection are of the same type - `<Record>`.
Here's how I display one collection:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SquareRecordsToDisplay}" Margin="10,35,10,70.667" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="#FFECCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateString}" Margin="0, 15, 0, 0"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0, 30, 0, 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Is there a way to display the two of them in different ways, without using multiple `ItemsControl` (i.e. using two `DataTemplates`)? Both have the same properties, as they are of the same type. I read similar questions and answers regarding the use of two `DataTemplates` in  the same `ItemControl`, but they don't solve my problem as they view objects of different types.

**EDIT:**

I tried to use DataTrigger but it makes my GUI crash... What am I doing wrong here?

```
  <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewStyle}" Value="ViewStyle.Square">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Grey" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewStyle}" Value="ViewStyle.Round">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Aqua" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Grid.Triggers>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateString}" Margin="0, 15, 0, 0"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0, 30, 0, 0"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

(ViewStyle is an enum)

Comment: I don't think you've been clear enough with this question. You say you have two different collections yet you want to display all the items across both of them with a single ItemsControl? No, your view model should be merging them into a single list for display by one control, especially if they're the same type i.e. Record. You may need to wrap them in a parent object to indicate how they should be displayed (possibly with a DataTrigger) but you'll have to be a bit more clear about exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is there a property on the `Record` that you can use to tell if a `Record` came from collection A or collection B? If yes, you can use a `CompositeCollection` merging the two collections and an `ItemTemplateSelector`.

Comment: @MarkFeldman `DataTrigger` seems to me like something that could solve this problem. Can I use it to show a certain `DataTemplate` if a property holds value A, and a different `DataTemplate` if a property holds value B?

Comment: @AviranKatz I've provided an answer with demo code below.

Comment: Also if ViewStyle is an enum then I think you might have to specify value as `"{x:Static local:ViewStyle.Square}"`, that was definitely the case in earlier versions of .NET although there's a chance that've changed it since.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I applied your answer with values `"square"` and `"round"`

Comment: @AviranKatz ah ok, good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a simple record containing a single field that you want to use to control which template gets selected:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Record[] Records {get; set;}

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.Records = new Record[] {
            new Record{Field = false},
            new Record{Field = true},
        };
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public bool Field { get; set; }
}
```

The following XAML will do the job. It sets the Item template to be a control that uses a DataTrigger to select from one of two styles, depending on the value of Field:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Records}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Control>
                <Control.Resources>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="StyleA">
                        <TextBlock Text="Style A" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="StyleB">
                        <TextBlock Text="Style B" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Control.Resources>
                <Control.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource StyleA}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Field}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource StyleB}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Control.Style>
            </Control>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the job